# $().keyup in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, keyup

I have a Greasemonkey script which uses jQuery. jQuery works fine, for example I can run

```
$('input[name="captcha"]').attr('value', 'abcd');
```

and it works.
Also I can run

```
$('input[name="captcha"]').keyup(function(){
    alert('');
});
```

in *Firebug console* and get the result. But in the Greasemonkey `keyup` doesn't seem to work at all. However `document.onkeyup = function() { alert('')}` also works well.

Any ideas how can I fix it or get similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, in fact I found how to get the same result. It's easy:

```
var captcha_field = $('input[name="captcha"]')[0];
captcha_field.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    alert('');
}, false);
```

(However would be nice to know is it how Greasemonkey is supposed to work or is it just a bug.)